# How to display "Comic Sans MS" in Linux?

Tags: fonts, operating-systems, html, web, css

I use "Comic Sans MS" font on my web page. The web page looks OK if I open it under Windows and MAC. But it does not work under Linux. How can I solve this problem? May be I can put the font on my web server? Is this font available for free? Can it slow down my page? Or may be I can replace "Comic Sans MS" by another font which is similar and is available on the 3 operation systems?

Comment: This isn't really SF releated.  Also http://bancomicsans.com/

Comment: Should really go on http://doctype.com.  Not really any place for this one on the trilogy sites.

Comment: Probably better on Superuser.com (it *is* a question that essentially boils down to installing fonts...)

Comment: I haven't seen it, but I can guarantee that your web page does not look OK to anyone anywhere.

Comment: It might look ok to me, I delete Comic Sans from all my windows machines :P

Answer (score 9):

1. Comic Sans is the world's most hated font (See http://bancomicsans.com/ )
2. If you still want to use Comic Sans you need to install the Comic Sans font. you don't say what Linux you're running, but these instructions are reasonably universal: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-True-Type-Fonts-on-Ubuntu

   - Note that this only helps you: Other Linux users may not have Comic Sans installed

Comment: There's a font I hate much much more than that, it's similar to the toys'r'us logo.

Comment: Comic Sans is the most common readable font for people with dyslexia! So If you want that all people can read it use Comic Sans or OpenDyslexic .

Answer (score 1):

[Linux Font Equivalents to Popular Web Typefaces - Monday By Noon](https://mondaybynoon.com/linux-font-equivalents-to-popular-web-typefaces/) has some relevant advice, both for displaying locally (install the [msttcorefonts](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) package) and for your visitors (use some other font that looks remotely similar, such as TSCu_Comic).

If you truly hate your readers, you could also provide Comic Sans as a web font, although in some jurisdictions that might be a copyright violation.

Comment: Comic Sans is the most common readable font for people with dyslexia! So If you want that all people can read it use Comic Sans or OpenDyslexic .